# select dropdown in focused state has blue border. How to remove

Tags: css

I have a `select` dropdown, with custom styling. It does not have a border, but when it is focused, it gets this green/blue border. Anyone know how to get rid of it?
[image]

Comment: use select:focus{ outline:none !important; }

Comment: `select:focus {outline: 0;}` Thats all you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Araz and @Mr. Alien said, `select:focus {outline: 0;}` worked. Thank you

Comment: Don't use `!important`, it is not required, and you'll end up in messy CSS later.